# Reboot without power cycle?

Tags: server, power-management, 16.10, reboot, init

I need a little help with this.

I have a server set up at home, running Ubuntu 16.10. When I reboot, it brings up a prompt that **interrupts the normal power-up sequence** to notify me of case intrusion. This is normal, because I recently performed upgrades.

But I am currently away from home and cannot reboot the system without it trying to await input.

So, I would like to reboot the system without a power cycle (killing all processes and running init again?). How would I do this?

Comment: Is the case intrusion monitoring an Ubuntu feature or baked into your bios?

If it's an Ubuntu warning and you know the service that reports it could you not disable it so it doesn't run then re-enable it on your return?

Comment: Baked into my bios, there's a physical switch that gets depressed when the cover is taken off. This case intrusion reporting is done during POST, I believe. When I get home today I'll disable it.

Comment: @Will Case intrusion is typically a setting that you can control in the BIOS of the system in question. I doubt this is coming from Ubuntu. Related:https://superuser.com/a/409470/357362

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is BIOS related and has nothing to do with the OS whether Ubuntu or not.

Comment: yes it does. I need to reboot without power cycling (for example, terminating and then restarting the `init` process, though I don't know how)

Comment: I think it's a relevant question @ElderGeek because there might be a way to essentially restart `Ubuntu` without completely rebooting. That's what the QP is asking.

In fact I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: Yeah, no reason to close it just because the BIOS hates reboots, I'm just trying to prevent a *full* reboot (soft reboot perhaps?)

Comment: Ok you & @Will have convinced me. CV retracted.

Comment: A related question on Unix & Linux stack exchange: [Restart all services without reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123678)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions that you could try to reboot without power-cycling the system.  Be aware that the 1st method may not umount drives before restarting, and you may want to script it to run after unmounting drives..

1. Run `sudo telinit u`.  This tells `init` to re-execute itself.
2. Use `kexec-reboot` or `kexec`.  They seem to accomplish the same tasks.

Check [the link here](https://github.com/error10/kexec-reboot) for the github page.

Install kexec-tools : `sudo apt-get install kexec-tools`

Usage is similar for both commands;

```
# kexec -l /boot/vmlinuz-linux --initrd=/boot/initramfs-linux.img --reuse-cmdline
# systemctl kexec
```

Further (and more involved) methods are [documented here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kexec).

Comment: doesn't `sudo telinit u` just restart `init` and nothing else? (all processes are owned by `init`, so maybe that reboots? dunno, let me try it)

Comment: [Yeah.](https://puu.sh/uW4M1/2209d94e92.png)

Comment: It restarts everything under init, so essentially yes.  But I've only done it on a barebones remote system, which worked like a reboot without power cycling the hardware on that setup.  I've never tried it on a full install but I imagine it yields the same result.

Comment: it does not restart SSH sessions, or bash running under those sessions then? (or byobu/tmux/screen?)

Comment: my uptime is still over a week ;/

Comment: Interesting.  Technically, I think it should restart everything that it started... Either way, option #2 should work and is actually usually used for server reboot to shorten downtime.  I'll play with option 1 at home tonight to look into it more.

Comment: option #2 downed my ssh session, waiting for a bit to see if it started again

Comment: @Dev Awesome.  Just to confirm, it rebooted without power cycling yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55932/discussion-between-dev-and-dorian).

Comment: This is a really useful piece of info. Are there any disadvantages to doing this instead of a complete reboot?

Comment: @Will Not that I'm aware of.  It seems to be practiced by people who run server blades because the BIOS POST procedure can be quite lengthy, and this allows you to bypass that wait time to maximise server up-time.  One concern, like I mentioned in my answer would be drives unmounting. But I tested it last night and it seemed to unmount fine before the reboot.  I may test again with a script to ensure programs are given a proper call to gracefully shutdown. So far, Chrome did not complain about it (no option to restore pages) but I'm curious myself.

Answer (score 1):

One method may be to boot into a new kernel using kexec

```
apt-get install kexec-tools
dpkg-reconfigure kexec-tools
```

This should in theory make reboots kexec into a new kernel to do a reboot without rebooting the machine